# How to limit access to Google Cloud Storage by IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for a way to limit access to objects inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket using IP address/es. I have seen an [article or tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/limit-bucket-access-in-google-cloud-storage-by-ip-address-d59029cab9c6) about it. However, it is using *terraform*. I don't have any capacity to make use of *terraform* as of now. Is there a way to achieve the same using the GC platform or console?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is not currently possible to restrict google cloud storage bucket by IP Address.There is a feature request raised for this at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63068776), which is still open. You can also add your concern further progress can be tracked there.

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71495883/18265638) by  guillaume blaquiere